# ERROR mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo un error en mi código:

```
$conexion = connect::con();

$compro_cod = "SELECT * FROM producte WHERE codprod = '$codprod'";
$existe = mysql_query($conexion,$compro_cod);

  if (mysql_num_rows($existe) > 0){

   print_r('Error: Ya existe ese codigo <br/> <a href="index.php?page=controller_accesori&op=list">Volver</a>');

   die();
} else {
    $sql = " INSERT INTO producte (id, accesori, imatge_accesori, email, codprod, marca, modelo, cantitat, data1, data2, pais, idioma, observaciones, valoracio)"
      . " VALUES ('$id','$accesori', '$imatge_accesori', '$email', '$codprod', '$marca', '$modelo', '$cantitat', '$data1', '$data2', '$pais', '$idioma', '$observaciones', '$valoracio')";

$res = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
connect::close($conexion);
return $res;
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que busque en bases de datos si exististe ese código, y si es así, que me muestre el print_r, pero me sale un error en el "mysql_num_rows" que me dice:

> mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: Hola `mysql_query` esta obsoleta y ademas el orden de los parámetros es inverso a como lo tienes ha de ser `mysql_query($compro_cod,$conexion);`, ademas estas mezclando los dos tipos `mysql` y `mysqli`, imagino que es error de tipeo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A petición de @KennyBarrera especificaré mejor mi respuesta:

En tú código estás mezclando instrucciones de conexión y consulta de mysql con las de mysqli. Es por ello que tu código arroja error. Debes elegir una sola. Te comento que las instrucciones de Mysql estan obsoletas desde la version de PHP 5.5.0 y desde la versión 7.0.0 están eliminadas. Más información sobre esto lo puedes observar [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-connect.php)

En vista de que la idea de nosotros que estamos en el mundo de la tecnología es innovar, mejorar y optimizar todo aquello que se pueda mi solución será orientada a mysqli (si eliges mysql pues solo reemplazas donde veas mysqli por mysql y listo!)

Ahora dejo el código completamente corregido, espero te pueda ser de ayuda:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "usuario", "contraseña", "nombre_bd");

$resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM producte WHERE codprod = '$codprod'");


  if ($resultado->num_rows > 0){

   print_r('Error: Ya existe ese codigo <br/> <a href="index.php?page=controller_accesori&op=list">Volver</a>');

} else {

$res = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO producte (id, accesori, imatge_accesori, email, codprod, marca, modelo, cantitat, data1, data2, pais, idioma, observaciones, valoracio)"
      . " VALUES ('$id','$accesori', '$imatge_accesori', '$email', '$codprod', '$marca', '$modelo', '$cantitat', '$data1', '$data2', '$pais', '$idioma', '$observaciones', '$valoracio')");

$mysqli->close();
return $res;
```

Comment: Huskie, bienvenido a SOes. Aun cuando concuerdo en la obsolencia de mysql, tu respuesta quizas no tiene el mejor enfoque. Aun cuando esta obsoleta esa clase, cada quien es libre de usarla, aun cuando suponga un riesgo de seguridad. Podrias enfocar tu respuesta a contestar la pregunta y creo que quedaria mejor. Saludos

Comment: Hmmm. El problema parte de que esta mezclando 2 MySql y Mysqli, no puede ni debe usar ambas, es por eso que le da error. No hago referencia a esto porque ya @Kevin se lo ha comentado directo en la pregunta así que si lo menciono de nuevo redundaría. Por otra parte las funciones conexión y demás de Mysql fueron eliminadas en PHP7 (cuyo tag esta colocado en su pregunta). Ya es obligatoria la migración hacia Mysqli o al menos a Pdo. Sería incorrecto que si tiene mezcla de los dos en su código (mysql y mysqli) orientarlo a que use el obsoleto para resolver a su problema. Gracias por la bienvenida

Comment: Exacto, me faltava la "i" para que ambos sea mysqli, ya que si ambos son mysql tambíen me daba error. Muchas gracias por la solución.

Comment: De nada bro. Me alegra haberte ayudado. un saludo!

Comment: Me parecio una A la respuesta de Huskie..
muchas gracias por el codigo de ejemplo... respuesta como estas son las mejores

Answer (score 0):

Lo que no entiendo, es que al ser un codigo mas "moderno" sea mas largo. El codigo corregido, tiene como 9 lineas y para hacer lo mismo con el código "mas viejo" yo uso:

$res=mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM  mitabla  WHERE "));
if ($res > 0){

}

Me desorienta porque cada vez hay que escribir mas para hacer lo mismo